# " NotImplementedError: sched is not yet implemented in Skulpt on line 4 " Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, skulpt

I've never seen this error before. I tried many times in changing it and looking in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html , but I don't know what's wrong. I'm trying to create a turtle game and I'm using sched to make two or more turtles move at different times. Is there another way to code this or do I have a stupid mistake? Here's some of my code with the error:

```
import turtle
import random
import time
import sched, time

Gameturtle=turtle.Turtle()

li = []
startTime=0
turtleTime=0
def main():
  wn=turtle.Screen();
  Setupuser(Gameturtle,wn)
  Setupcontrols(wn)
  Border(wn)
  s = sched.scheduler(time.time, ti*emphasized text*me.sleep)
  def print_time(a='default'):
    print("From print_time", time.time(), a)


  InsertEnemyturtleintolist(li)
  starttime=time.time()
  print ("Starttime:",starttime)
```